# Lan, vpn on Amazon EC2, how to?

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2

The problem is as follows:

I have 2 windows2003 server instances running on the cloud.

1) How can I create a local area network from these 2 instances?

2) Assuming that I want to create a VPN network from these 2 instances, how do I do that?

(I'm not very good in networking, therefor the above problem description might be incomplete or not very clear.)

A detailed answer or clarification would be praised and appreciated!

---

What I tried:

1) Setting up OpenVPN, but I got lost in the process. 
2) Creating a VPN from windows2003 server in the following manner:
on instance a): 
set up a dhcp server;
set up an "accept income vpn" connection; with the followin tcp ip settings: obtain an ip from the dhcp server;

on instance b): 
created a new vpn connection, tried to connect to intance A, using the instance A static IP but error 806 was thrown, something relate to a GRE protocol.

Comment: Do you mean you want to communicate between them securely, as opposed to over the Internet (actually over Amazon's switches).

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully set up OpenVPN connection between my firewall at home and my EC2 instances.  It works quite well, but I'm using Linux at both endpoints, so my experience won't directly translate to your config.

As much as I hate IPSec VPNs, you might find that an easier route to try.  Have you looked into Amazon's new "[Virtual Private Cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/)" service yet?  This sounds ideal for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an admin, but if you're going to try and setup a VPN here are a few things to bear in mind:

1. Make sure you're using the public DNS name when trying to talk to an instance from outside of the Amazon network.  Better yet, assign an Elastic IP (EIP) to the instance.  That way, if your instance crashes and you need to create a new one, you don't have to redo the configuration on the part of the network at your offices.
2. Make sure you open up ALL of the ports on the AWS firewall **for your company's IP address / network range** (not for the whole world).  If you knew the ins and outs already, I would say just open the ports you need, but since you don't...